# Rear derailleur can't reach the smallest gear (Shimano 10 Speed Road)

Tags: shimano, compatibility, shifting

I recently assembled the following combination of parts:

- Shimano 10-speed STIs (non-series, between 105 and Ultegra, ca. 2003)
- MicroShift 10-speed cassette (11-28)
- Tiagra 10-speed rear derailleur (Tiagra 4700-GS)

The problem is, either I set the tension low enough to reach the smallest cog in the back, but then shifting in the higher range isn't smooth and gears are skipped. Or I use higher tension, but then I can't reach the smallest cog and effectively run on a 9-speed.

It's like at some point, I have to go 2 clicks up or down to reach the next gear (somewhere in the middle of the range).

I tried with an old Ultegra (RD-6600) rear derailleur, but that couldn't reach all the gears. I remember from years ago, that a 12-27 cassette with that derailleur and the same lever wasn't a problem.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the rest of the setup? Thinking of necessary spacers if the 10-speed cassette is mixed with a newer wheel/11-speed road hub? That would need 1+1,85mm spacers to fit, iirc...

Comment: I tried several combinations, but it didn't make a difference. The Tiagra derailleur easily covers the entire distance between the lowest and highest cog, and then some.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tiagra 4700 has a different cable pull. It's not compatible.

Comment: Yup, seems to be correct, for reference https://www.bicycles.net.au/forums/viewtopic.php?t=92555, RD-4700 is the oddball, here.

Comment: I ordered a different one, let's see, but after reading up on things a bit, that seems to be the most likely solution. It's weird though that it works quite well over 9 gears ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that an Ultegra or 105 from 2003 would have been 9 speed. That would mean your cassette needs to be 9-speed too.

You can probably verify the shifter speed by clicking all the way from one end of the range to the other. If it is a 9-speed shifter, there should be 8 clicks to get from highest to lowest and vice-versa.

Comment: Hmm then maybe I have the year wrong, it's definitely 10 speed and I've used it for that before, successfully ... there's 9 clicks between highest and lowest setting.